# How do you get rid of the default image for radio and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css

I've been trying to get rid of a a border and image that appears when I've skinned my controls (checkbox and radio buttons) does anyone know what that could be and how to get rid of it I've been using IE 10 and chrome and getting a default picture over the checkbox what gets rid of it the plugin I've been using is [widowmaker](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.thing {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance:    none;
   appearance:         none;
}
```

However, for inputs for instance, you might need to set border: 0; and background to a specific color, sometimes (Chrome in my case) shows a horrible border and I must reset it. It might as well happen in other browsers. It might also happen for other elements (such as the ones you're mentioning).

Using appearance: none; gives you the freedom of using custom CSS in most mayor browsers. Try to reset the "things" you want to "delete" by using these rules.

Here for more: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for you're reply I tried you're code and had no luck could there be any reason why my page doesn't work when their demonstration does on my local machine. I can't seem to see where the problem lies. I have taken out all my css files and styles Iand I still get the same problem

Comment: Strange. Make a fiddle so that I can check the live code and then I'll maybe able to help better. Luck